# React Native TabBarIOS "More …” Button Crashes

Tags: react-native

When I add more than 5 tabs to my tab bar a “More …” button appears in place of the overflowing items. When that button is clicked in my iPhone 6s emulator it crashes saying that the tab index is out of bounds of the array.

To REPRO .... I have a new v0.22 project. Here is my index.ios.js which crashes when the “More …” button is clicked...

```
 /**
 * Sample React Native App
 * https://github.com/facebook/react-native
 */

import React, {
    AppRegistry,
    Component,
    StyleSheet,
    Text,
    View,
    TabBarIOS,
} from 'react-native';

class SampleTabsIos extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            selectedTab: 'TabOne'
        };
    }

    render() {
        return (
                <TabBarIOS>
                    <TabBarIOS.Item
                        title="Tab 1"
                        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'TabOne'}
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.setState({
                              selectedTab: 'TabOne',
                            });
                        }}>
                        <Text>Tab 1</Text>
                    </TabBarIOS.Item>

                    <TabBarIOS.Item
                        title="Tab 2"
                        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'TabTwo'}
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.setState({
                              selectedTab: 'TabTwo',
                            });
                        }}>
                        <Text>Tab 2</Text>
                    </TabBarIOS.Item>

                    <TabBarIOS.Item
                        title="Tab 3"
                        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'TabThree'}
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.setState({
                              selectedTab: 'TabThree',
                            });
                        }}>
                        <Text>Tab 3</Text>
                    </TabBarIOS.Item>

                    <TabBarIOS.Item
                        title="Tab 4"
                        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'TabOne'}
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.setState({
                              selectedTab: 'TabOne',
                            });
                        }}>
                        <Text>Tab 4</Text>
                    </TabBarIOS.Item>

                    <TabBarIOS.Item
                        title="Tab 5"
                        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'TabFive'}
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.setState({
                              selectedTab: 'TabFive',
                            });
                        }}>
                        <Text>Tab 5</Text>
                    </TabBarIOS.Item>

                    <TabBarIOS.Item
                        title="Tab 6"
                        selected={this.state.selectedTab === 'TabSix'}
                        onPress={() => {
                            this.setState({
                              selectedTab: 'TabSix',
                            });
                        }}>
                        <Text>Tab 6</Text>
                    </TabBarIOS.Item>
                </TabBarIOS>
        );
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container   : {
        flex           : 1,
        justifyContent : 'center',
        alignItems     : 'center',
        backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
    },
    welcome     : {
        fontSize : 20,
        textAlign: 'center',
        margin   : 10,
    },
    instructions: {
        textAlign   : 'center',
        color       : '#333333',
        marginBottom: 5,
    },
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('SampleTabsIos', () => SampleTabsIos);
```

and if it's helpful - here is the crashed / stack trace

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 9223372036854775807 beyond bounds [0 .. 5]'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109c91f65 __exceptionPreprocess + 165
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000108e8fdeb objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109b75a94 -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:] + 212
    3   SampleTabsIos                       0x00000001087bec98 -[RCTTabBar tabBarController:shouldSelectViewController:] + 184
    4   UIKit                               0x000000010b78b791 -[UITabBarController _tabBarItemClicked:] + 149
    5   UIKit                               0x000000010b5a31fa -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    6   UIKit                               0x000000010b955f79 -[UITabBar _sendAction:withEvent:] + 451
    7   UIKit                               0x000000010b5a31fa -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    8   UIKit                               0x000000010b707504 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    9   UIKit                               0x000000010b7077d0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    10  UIKit                               0x000000010b95af9f -[UITabBar(Static) _buttonUp:] + 103
    11  UIKit                               0x000000010b5a31fa -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:] + 92
    12  UIKit                               0x000000010b707504 -[UIControl sendAction:to:forEvent:] + 67
    13  UIKit                               0x000000010b7077d0 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:] + 311
    14  UIKit                               0x000000010b706906 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:] + 601
    15  UIKit                               0x000000010b60daa3 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:] + 835
    16  UIKit                               0x000000010b60e691 -[UIWindow sendEvent:] + 865
    17  UIKit                               0x000000010b5c0752 -[UIApplication sendEvent:] + 263
    18  UIKit                               0x000000010b59bfcc _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue + 6693
    19  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109bbe0a1 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 17
    20  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109bb3fcc __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 556
    21  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109bb3483 __CFRunLoopRun + 867
    22  CoreFoundation                      0x0000000109bb2e98 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 488
    23  GraphicsServices                    0x000000010e664ad2 GSEventRunModal + 161
    24  UIKit                               0x000000010b5a1676 UIApplicationMain + 171
    25  SampleTabsIos                       0x0000000108716d0f main + 111
    26  libdyld.dylib                       0x000000010d1a892d start + 1
    27  ???                                 0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: There is an archived item on GitHub. It describes the problem, but doesn't have an answer. Surely the More... button works somehow. Maybe just seeing a working sample of it in action will help me figure out what I'm doing wrong.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3728

Comment: This issue is on Product Pains: https://productpains.com/post/react-native/clicking-on-overflow-more-in-tabbarios-raises-nsrangeexception

Comment: Hi @AntonNiklasson - do you think I was wrong for bringing it to SO and offering a bounty? The ProductPains site doesn't seem to get any traffic. Really looking for help to get this resolved.

Comment: I guess there was nothing with putting a bounty on it. Productpains will probably not solve this, since they have such a huge backlog at this point. I will look at this tomorrow. I'll let you know if I figure something out.

Comment: Just to let you know: I will just limit my TabBar to five items for now. Hope you find a way to work around it :)

Comment: We're hard coding a max of 5, that's our answer. but the "More..." functionality is really nice to have. Thanks for any time you have to look around the issue.

Comment: I am stuck with the same problem. I think the only solution for now is to set the fifth tabbaritem to mimic the More Button. And then onPress, recreate the same functionality that iOS already has (new UITableViewController shows up modally... which I am guessing is a React Native List View. But I'm not 100% sure since I'm still learning RN)